# sessions in cakephp4 vs. cakephp2.3

Tags: session, cakephp, cakephp-4.x

Currently i am rewriting a cakephp2.3 application in cakephp4+.

in my controller (just for test reasons) I wrote this five lines.

```php
$session = $this->request->getSession();

$session->write([
    'TDSPeople.active' => $this->request->getData('active'),
    'TDSPeople.filter' => $this->request->getData('filter')
]);

debug($session);
```

my debug output only shows:

```php
object(Cake\Http\Session) id:0 {
    protected _engine => null
    protected _started => true
    protected _lifetime => (int) 1440
    protected _isCLI => false
}
```

what went wrong?

Do i have to declare that I want to use the session component or is it a configuration problem related to working on my development server without SSL.

Any help appreciated

thx

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're having? That you don't see the session data in the debug output?

Comment: mainly yes. I thought I should see them there. Am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, the debug information of the session object will not show the session data. Check  `$session->read()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the hidden hint of ndm´s comment the problem ist solved the data is where it should be and all is fine. sorry for the confusion. I´ve tried to access the keys in $session->read (obviously) directly and there it appeared.